# How should I structure controller actions that share templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a `User` model, and an `Invoice` model with a `belongs_to :user` association.

Now I'm creating a `new` action for my `InvoicesController`, and the view that will be rendered. The view will have a select-element for selecting the user that this invoice will belong to.

So I need to fetch those users somewhere; my instinct is to leave this kind of thing out of the view. I end up with this:

```
def new
  @users = User.all
end
```

The form submit action is `create`. When the creation fails for some reason, I re-render the `new` action's view.

```
def create
  invoice = Invoice.new params[:invoice]
  if invoice.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Invoice created!'
    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => invoice.id
  else
    @users = User.all
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

But as you can see, in order the re-render the `new` action, I have to fetch the users again.

This is just an example, but consider that I have some forms with several select-elements filled from the database, or similar constructs. That turns into an awful lot of repetition.

So how should I structure my controller in this situation?

- Should I simply use `User.all` from my view?
- Should I call `new` from within `create` to do the fetching for me?
- Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I'd use a `before_filter`.  For example you'd do something like:

```
  before_filter :fetch_all_users, :only => [:new, :create]

protected

  def fetch_all_users
    @users = User.all
  end
```

For 90% of my controllers I use the [inherited resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) plugin.  It cuts down the amount of controller code you need to write for CRUD controllers, which also means you can cut down on the amount of tests you need to write.

Comment: But that would fetch the complete user list in my `list` and `show` actions too. That sounds expensive.

Comment: You can use `only` and `except` to scope to a specific set of actions.

Comment: Is that still true in rails 3? I know User.where(...) and the like would use delayed execution and only hit the db if a user object is actually accessed, is that true of User.all as well?

Comment: I believe User.all will be delayed too because it's just a scope.

Answer (score 0):

For me:

[What's the rails way to load other models collections for new, edit update and create actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297269/whats-the-rails-way-to-load-other-models-collections-for-new-edit-update-and-cr)

It's not a good approach for my situation. Where after ".save", I send redirect_to to an another action, if I use before_filter and ".save" returns true, the fetch_all_users is called unnecessary