# What's the rails way to load other models collections for new, edit update and create actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, crud, has-many

How is the best way to load Category model, for ProductController in new, edit update and create actions

Product has categories collection

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end
```

Always for new, edit, create and update actions, I need to load the categories collection to populate a check_box_tag list

The "baby steps" for this situation is:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::AdminApplicationController

 def new
   @product = Product.new
   @categories = Category.all
 end

 def edit
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
   @categories = Category.all
 end

 def create
   @product = Product.new(params[:product])
   if @product.save
     flash[:notice] = 'Product was successfully created'
     redirect_to edit_admin_product_path(@product)
   else
     @categories = Category.all
     render :new
  end
 end

 def update
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
   @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
   if @product.save
     flash[:notice] = 'Product was successfully updated'
     redirect_to edit_admin_product_path(@product)
   else
     @categories = Category.all
     render :edit
   end
 end
end
```

I don't want to load always Category.all in different situations for same purpose

Options:

First - load categories over the view:

```
<% Category.all.each do |cat| %>
  <li>
    <%= check_box_tag .... %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

:/

Second - load categories over the ProductsHelper :

```
module ProductsHelper

  def categories
   Category.all
  end

end
```

:/

"Third" - Exist a filter like 'before_render'?

```
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::AdminApplicationController

  before_render :load_categories :edit, :new

  def load_categories
    @categories = Category.all
  end

end
```

:D :D :D

What's the rails way for this situations?

Best Regards,
Pablo Cantero

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179423/how-should-i-structure-controller-actions-that-share-templates

Comment: It's not a good approach for my situation. Where after ".save", I send redirect_to to an another action, if I use before_filter and ".save" returns true, the fetch_all_users is called unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, or if needed elsewhere, in application_controller.rb:

```
def all_categories
  @all_categories ||= Category.all
end
helper_method :all_categories
```

The first time it's called, it will hit the db, and later it will return the controller instance variable.

Comment: Thanks! Great solution, I will use it. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the first option in this case.

### Edit

As I've mentioned in the comments, it depends on the situation. A relatively clean way for me would be to define a `categories` method in the controller and declare it a helper. Then call that when you need it in the view.

However (and this is the situation I envisaged when first answering) if it's a single form field I'd simply call the model from the view just for the sake of simplicity - methods like

```
helper_method :all_categories
private
def all_categories
  Category.all
end
```

aren't exactly the most elegant code.

Comment: You mean have the view call `Category.all`? Why should the view be aware of this knowledge? What if later there are too many categories and only a subset should be loaded?

Comment: View calling a model?! Not is MVC! :/  

I think that, also a helper (ProductsHelper) calling a model is bad for MVC principles. The helper for me is a part of the view

Comment: @Matt then you refactor and put it into a helper.

Comment: @Pablo Yes it's a violation of MVC fair enough. However in this case you can add indirection and encapsulation and what not, but it's sacrificing simplicity on the altar of your ideals. If that's worth it for you, fair enough. *De gustibus non est disputandum.* My personal opinion is that simplicity is best in a case like this. If your use case is more complex, by all means do a `before_filter`.

Comment: @Jakub before_filter was the solution used here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179423/how-should-i-structure-controller-actions-that-share-templates - Shtééf - 

It's not a good approach for my situation. Where after ".save", I send redirect_to to an another action, if I use before_filter and ".save" returns true, the fetch_all_users is called unnecessary

Comment: Maybe the best way is refactory my controller to don't use redirect_to anymore and change it for "render :action" + "before_filter :load_dependecies, :only => [:create, :update, :new, :edit]" like @Shtééf solution

Comment: In Rails 3 won't a needless call to fetch_all_users be so cheap it won't really matter? If I understand rails 3 correctly, it won't actually make a db call unless you actually attempt to access the users.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer your third solution. I don't like using business logic in view, because I guess gathering information is the controller's task, in the view layer I just want to use the data and the helper methods. Using Category.all in the view layer can be good when you're using cache, but in this case you should send an expired signal somehow if it changed.

Your first solution has many repeated lines, which you can erase by using your third solution. So I would choose the third one :)