# Where does the menu partial generation code belong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

In my application.html.erb layout i'm rendering the partial shared/_menu.html.erb that contains the following code

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <% Post.all.each do |post| %>
      <%= link_to post.title, post.permalink %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The fact that I make a call on the Model from my view seems rather problematic in the sense of respecting MVC to me. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I should solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the rails way to load other models collections for new, edit update and create actions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297269/whats-the-rails-way-to-load-other-models-collections-for-new-edit-update-and-cr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `before_filter` to your ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :define_posts

def define_posts
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

Then your menu should look like that:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <%= link_to post.title, post.permalink %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Another approach is to create helper method in your ApplicationController:

```
helper_mathod :posts

def posts
  @posts ||= Post.all
end
```

So you can call it directly form your menu:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
      <%= link_to post.title, post.permalink %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Second approach looks little cleaner.

And one nowadays solution is to use [Decent Exposure gem](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure):

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure